# isPrime function in Haskell is generating non-exhaustive patterns error. What is wrong?

Tags: haskell

I am writing an isPrime function in Haskell and I keep getting errors like "Non-exhaustive patterns in function isPrime". What cases am I not considering?

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False 
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime n = (length [x | x<-[2 .. n-1],  mod n x == 0]) > 0 = False 
| otherwise = True
```

Comment: The code, as written, does not compile. Show us your real code.

Comment: After the obvious fix, it [seems to work fine](https://ideone.com/e0iHM0).

Comment: What is the obvious fix?

Comment: Check the link I posted above for the full code.

Comment: Using `null` to check for an empty list is more efficient than computing its length, then comparing that to 0.

Comment: Also, you don't need two cases. `isPrime n = not (null [x | ...])`.

Answer (score 0):

Posting on behalf of @chi

```hs
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False 
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime n
  | (length [x | x<-[2 .. n-1],  mod n x == 0]) > 0 = False 
  | otherwise = True 


main = do
  print (isPrime 7)
  print (isPrime 8)
  print (isPrime 9)
  print (isPrime 10)
  print (isPrime 11)
  print (isPrime 12)
```

Stdout

```sh
True
False
False
False
True
False
```